# If a String is immutable in JavaScript why does the following code mutate a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have read the input as a string and, after splitting it, the string becomes an object.

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.on('data',(c)=>{
    in += c;
});
process.stdin.on('end',()=>{
    spliter(in);
});
function spliter(in){
    console.log(typeof(in));
    in = in.split('\n');
    console.log(typeof(in));
}
```

Comment: where is any string being mutated? this global variable `in += c;` which you call spliter like `spliter(in)` is unchanged in the code you've posted ... the argument `in`, you change to be an array, but you haven't "mutated a string"

Comment: arrays are a type of object in JavaScript. `typeof []` will return `object`. If you want to determine whether it's actually an array, you can use the isArray method it found on the Array constructor: `Array.isArray([])` returns true

Comment: Additionally, strings are not immutable in JavaScript. Not sure where you got that misconception. Only const declared variables are immutable.

Comment: @JacobPenney - are you sure? Every single bit of documentation about javascript disagrees with you

Comment: @JacobPenney Strings (and all of primitives) are immutable in JS. Their prototypes aren't, but that's another question...

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: When you define a variable there are two parts, a reference to a value- and the value itself.  Think of it like a pointer.  In a constant you can't change what its pointing to but you can still sometimes change stuff about the value.  If the value is immutable but you don't define it as a constant than you can just point to a new value.  Remember, you can have a `const` and `let` defined var point to the same object and mutate the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, in the example provided, the string [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) is not being mutated.

The variable is being [re-assigned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) to the value returned by the [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method, which is being called on a [String wrapper object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#primitive_wrapper_objects_in_javascript), which is automatically used when calling a method on a string.     ​

```js
let myString = 'Hello World!';

console.log("BEFORE reassignment - variable type is: " + typeof(myString));  // string 

myString  = myString.split(' ');  // <----- method called on String object wrapper, returns an array, which is re-assigned to the myString variable   

console.log(myString); //  ['Hello', 'World!']

console.log("AFTER reassignment - variable type is: " + typeof(myString)); // object
```

Below is some further context:

> The set of types in the JavaScript language consists of [primitive values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#primitive_values) and [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#objects).
> Source:  [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#javascript_types)

A `string` is a `primitive value`.

In JavaScript, [all primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) are **immutable** and **have no methods**, however:
​

> It is important not to confuse a primitive itself with a variable assigned a primitive value. The variable may be reassigned a new value, but the existing value can not be changed in the ways that objects, arrays, and functions can be altered.
> Source:  [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)

Even though primitive types have no methods, it is possible to call a method on a primitive because all primitive values, except for `null` and `undefined`, have object equivalents that wrap around the primitive values:

- [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) for the string primitive.
- [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) for the number primitive.
- [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) for the bigint primitive.
- [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) for the boolean primitive.
- [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) for the symbol primitive.

Source: [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#primitive_wrapper_objects_in_javascript)

When you call a [String instance method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#instance_methods) on a `string` primitive the following occurs:

- The primitive value is temporarily converted into an object
- The object's method property is used
  (e.g [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) will return a new `string` and [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) will return an `array` of strings)
- The object is converted back to a primitive

Sources:

- [Head First JavaScript Programming](https://www.google.com.au/books/edition/Head_First_JavaScript_Programming/GhssAwAAQBAJ) (2014), page 306.
- [JavaScript Programmer's Reference](https://www.google.com.au/books/edition/JavaScript_Programmer_s_Reference/XJrXl71TITIC) (2010), page 157.

Answer (score 2):

Your code **does not** mutate the string.

---

Strings (along with the other primitive types) are **immutable** in JS.

Mutating something means that changing it *without* creating another one.

String modifier methods return a new string, but doesn't change the original, for example:

```
const a = 'Hello world!'
const b = a.slice(0,5)

console.log(a) //Hello world!
console.log(b) //Hello
```

However, you can still reassign a string variable with a new string (but that's not mutation):

```
let a = 'Hello world!'
a = a.slice(0,5)

console.log(a) //Hello
```

---

Your code is a bit more complicated. `String#split()` returns an *array of strings*, but doesn't mutate the original:

```
const a = 'Hello world!'
const b = a.split('o')

console.log(a) //Hello world!
console.log(b) //['Hell', ' w', 'rld!']
```

Arrays are (in fact) objects, and they *are* mutable, but not the strings (and other primitives) they contain.

Comment: @user1063287 I appreciate your efforts to improve this answer, but now it contains a lot of information unrelated to actually answering the question. A detailed answer is good, but an overly detailed answer may make the answer to the question harder to find, especially, when the question isn't a very general one.

Comment: no worries, have rolled back answer to last edit and added detailed response to another answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you modify a string variable, javascript doesn't actually modify the string that's in memory, it instead creates a brand new string that looks like a modification of the initial string:

```js
    let str = "     hi      ";
    str = str.trim(); // a new string "hi" is created
    console.log(str);
```

That is all javascript means by saying its strings are immutable. If you want to prevent a string variable from being changed, you can use `const`:

```js
const str = "Can't change me";
str = "Want to bet?"  // throws error.
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, you are NOT mutating the string

If you were, the following code (based on your code) would output Object in both console.log's

```js
let x = 'this is a string';
function spliter(x){
    x = x.split('\n');
    console.log(typeof(x));
}
spliter(x);
console.log(typeof(x));
```